# Add/Remove Select Lists using jQuery - selectID not being sent in POST

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, select

I'm using the code from this site: [Add/Remove Select Lists Using jQuery](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/create-add-remove-select-lists-using-jquery/)

I've got the display portion all set up, but when I submit the form, there's nothing set in the $_POST that would allow me to read the users' selection(s).

Here's the form I've got set up:

```
<?php
    <form id='setTasks' action='?action=ae&view=departmentTasks' method='post'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td valign='top'>
                    <select name='selectfrom' id='select-from' multiple size='5'>";
                        for ($i = 0; $i < count($unusedTasks); $i++)
                            echo "<option value='" . $unusedTasks[$i]['taskID'] . "'>" . $unusedTasks[$i]['taskName'] . "</option>";
                echo "</select>
                </td>
                <td valign='top'><a href='JavaScript:void(0);' id='btn-add'>Add &raquo;</a></td>
                <td valign='bottom'><a href='JavaScript:void(0);' id='btn-remove'>&laquo; Remove</a></td>
                <td>
                    <select name='selectto' id='select-to' multiple size='5'>";
                        for ($i = 0; $i < count($departmentTasks); $i++)
                            echo "<option value='" . $departmentTasks[$i]['taskID'] . "'>" . $departmentTasks[$i]['taskName'] . "</option>";
            echo "</select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='departmentID' value='" . $departmentID . "' />
                    <input type='hidden' name='submitFinal' value='1' />
                    <input type='submit' name='submitForm' value='Assign Tasks' />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick='javascript:history.go(-1);' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>";
?>
```

And the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-add').click(function(){
        $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
            $('#select-to').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
                $(this).remove();
            });
    });
    $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
        $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
            $('#select-from').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
            $(this).remove();
        });
        }); 
    });
```

The front end (moving items back a forth) works fine, but when i do a var_dump($_POST) I don't get any information from the select fields.  Anybody able to see what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't get any form data because the select lists only send the *selected* items.

One solution: Loop through all options and set them as selected before posting.

Another solution: Copy the information you need from the options into a hidden field before posting.